# Laravel WebSockets Custom Handler class does not work when APP_DEBUG=false is in the .evn file

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, laravel-websockets

In my Laravel project I have implemented Laravel WebSockets following this article: https://freek.dev/1228-introducing-laravel-websockets-an-easy-to-use-websocket-server-implemented-in-php

I have implemented `MyCustomWebSocketHandler` class and everything works fine with `APP_DEBUG=true` in the `.env` file.

But when `APP_DEBUG=false`, non of the implemenations in the `MyCustomWebSocketHandler` class is being executed. It uses the default `BeyondCode\LaravelWebSockets\WebSockets\WebSocketHandler` class.

After searching for solutions on Google, I found this: https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-websockets/issues/296

But the comment of `matheusb-comp` is not true. It still does not work, even `class MyCustomWebSocketHandler implements MessageComponentInterface { }`.

How can I fix it that with `APP_DEBUG=false` in the `.env` file, the Laravel WebSockets still works with the implementations in the `MyCustomWebSocketHandler` class?

Comment: Do you get any error in your laravel.log?

Comment: No, I get no errors. It just uses the default `WebSocketHandler` class instead of my `MyCustomWebSocketHandler` class.